# Stuck whilst applying the step missing from decoding a PNG file, in Luau (defiltering)

Tags: lua, png, binaryfiles, decoding, luau

I am attempting to decode PNG files in Luau, and so far I have made great progress, to the point of being able to make out the image in the final, decoded result, despite clearly being incorrect. The one thing I need to fix is the de-filtering (reconstruction) process.

So far I have correctly parsed the different chunks of the file, and decompressed the IDAT chunk with an external library. I have also converted the raw data to the format I need (a table consisting of numbers between 0-1, 4 for each pixel, each number corresponding to an RGBA channel), but the data is "filtered" before being compressed in order to optimize the compression. This of course means that I need to reverse this process (de-filter) in order to view the correct results.

For every scanline, I am correctly getting the byte used to determine which [filter function](https://www.w3.org/TR/png-3/#9Filter-types) was used on the scanline. All I need to do is apply the correct function to reverse the filtering per scanline (Recon(x)). To test this, I'm using the test images provided by [PNGSuite](http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/pngsuite_fil_png.html) (specifically the colored ones), because only one type of filter is used on the entire image, which makes it easier to see the results of each individual de-filtering function.

Here are the results for each image:

- 0 (No Operation):
  output image is correct!

### [image: Test image f00n2c08.png after being decoded]

- 1 (Sub)
  image looks nearly correct, but the red channel is a little weird:

### [image: Test image f01n2c08.png after being decoded]

- 2 (Up)
  the shapes in the image resemble the correct result, but it's definitely very wrong:

### [image: Test image f02n2c08.png after being decoded]

- 3 (Average)
  the number in the image can be seen, but otherwise, it's nearly completely incomprehensible:

### [image: Test image f03n2c08.png after being decoded]

- 4 (Paeth Predictor)
  shows patterns similar to Up, but it's also very wrong:

### [image: Test image f04n2c08.png after being decoded]

(Note: Although I know it's not a good idea, i don't plan on supporting bit depths below 8, and for testing purposes, I'm only supporting a bit depth of 8, but do plan on supporting 16-bit color later on.)

(And for any of those familiar with Lua but not with Luau, my code does make heavy use of type annotations and the built-in *buffer library*. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out how these work, but they are officially documented here if needed):

- https://luau-lang.org/syntax#type-annotations
- https://luau-lang.org/library#buffer-library

```lua
-- Util function to query a certain number of bits from the image data bytes
-- Will be useful if support for bit depths other than 8 are introduced
-- From here, CurrentPos shall be measured in bits instead of bytes
CurrentPos = 0
local CurrentBuffer:buffer = DecompressedData
local function GetInt(BitDepth:number):number
    local ByteIndex:number = math.floor(CurrentPos / 8)
    local BitOffset:number = (CurrentPos * BitDepth) % 8

    local Int:number = 0
    
    if BitDepth == 8 then
        Int = buffer.readu8(CurrentBuffer, ByteIndex)
    elseif BitDepth == 16 then
        Int = buffer.readu16(CurrentBuffer, ByteIndex)
    elseif BitDepth == 32 then
        Int = buffer.readu32(CurrentBuffer, ByteIndex)
    else
        -- For bit depths less than 8, you need to handle bit-wise extraction
        local Byte:number = buffer.readu8(CurrentBuffer, ByteIndex)
        local Shift:number = 8 - BitDepth - BitOffset
        return bit32.rshift(bit32.band(Byte, bit32.lshift(0xFF, BitOffset)), Shift)
    end

    CurrentPos += BitDepth
    return Int
end
    
-- Defilter process
-- Start by splitting the bytes into scanlines

-- How many bytes are in a scanline? (not including the filter byte)
local ScanlineBytes:number = math.floor(ImageStruct.BitDepth * ImageStruct.Size.X / 8) 
local PixelBytes:number = 1 -- how many bytes in a single pixel?
local Scanlines:{buffer} = {} -- List of scanlines processed

if ImageStruct.ColorType == 2 then -- Truecolor
    PixelBytes = 3
elseif ImageStruct.ColorType == 3 then -- Indexed color
    PixelBytes = 1 -- lol....
elseif ImageStruct.ColorType == 6 then -- Truecolor with alpha
    PixelBytes = 4
end -- No support for greyscale color types yet sory
ScanlineBytes *= PixelBytes -- The amount of bytes in a scanline is actually the width * how many bytes are in one pixel.

-- For every scanline
for Y:number = 1, ImageStruct.Size.Y do
    
    -- Get this scanline's filter byte
    local FilterByte:number = GetInt(8)
    
    -- These should be unfiltered
    --local PreviousScanLine:buffer? = Scanlines[Y - 1] -- Warning: will be null if we are on the first scanline
    local PreviousScanLine:buffer? = nil
    local PreviousByte:number = 0 -- Currently unused variable
    
    local Scanline:buffer = buffer.create(ScanlineBytes)
    local ScanlineUnfiltered:buffer = buffer.create(ScanlineBytes)
        
    -- For every byte on the scanline (defiltering works with bytes, not pixels, so we can disregard bit depth for now)
    for X:number = 0, ScanlineBytes-1, 1 do
            
        -- Get this byte
        local Byte:number = GetInt(8)
            
        --local ByteA:number = PreviousByte
            
        -- Get the byte in the previous pixel (the result should be 0 if we're on the first pixel)
        local ByteA:number = if (X > PixelBytes) then buffer.readu8(Scanline, X - PixelBytes) else 0
            
        -- Get the same byte in the previous scanline (the result should be 0 if we're on the first scanline)
        local ByteB:number = if PreviousScanLine then buffer.readu8(PreviousScanLine, X) else 0
            
        -- Get the byte in the previous pixel on the previous scanline (the result should be 0 if blah blah blah you get the point)
        local ByteC:number = if (PreviousScanLine and (X > PixelBytes)) then buffer.readu8(PreviousScanLine, X - PixelBytes) else 0
        
        -- Apply appropriate defiltering function
        local DefilteredByte:number = m:ApplyDefiltering(FilterByte, Byte, ByteA, ByteB, ByteC) % 256

        buffer.writeu8(ScanlineUnfiltered, X, Byte)
        buffer.writeu8(Scanline, X, DefilteredByte)
        --PreviousByte = DefilteredByte
        PreviousByte = Byte
    end
    --GetInt(8)
    PreviousScanLine = ScanlineUnfiltered
    table.insert(Scanlines, Scanline)
end
    
    
-- Finally, we need to actually get the pixels
local Pixels:{number} = {}
for Y:number = 1, ImageStruct.Size.Y do
    local Scanline:buffer = Scanlines[Y]
    
    -- Set variables used by GetInt (we are reading from the current scanline)
    CurrentBuffer = Scanline
    CurrentPos = 0
    
    for X:number = 1, ImageStruct.Size.X, 1 do
        local R:number, G:number, B:number, A:number
        
        if ImageStruct.ColorType == 2 then -- Truecolor
            R = GetInt(8) / 255
            G = GetInt(8) / 255
            B = GetInt(8) / 255
            A = 1
        elseif ImageStruct.ColorType == 3 then -- Indexed color
            local PaletteIndex:number = GetInt(8)
            local Color:Color3 = ImageStruct.Pallette[PaletteIndex] -- Get the color from the pallette (PLTE)
            R = Color.R
            G = Color.G
            B = Color.B
            A = 1
        elseif ImageStruct.ColorType == 6 then -- Truecolor with alpha
            R = GetInt(8) / 255
            G = GetInt(8) / 255
            B = GetInt(8) / 255
            A = GetInt(8) / 255
        end
        
        table.insert(Pixels, R)
        table.insert(Pixels, G)
        table.insert(Pixels, B)
        table.insert(Pixels, A)
    end
end
```

Additionally, here's the function that applies de-filtering to a byte:

```lua
function m:ApplyDefiltering(FilterByte:number, Byte:number, ByteA:number, ByteB:number, ByteC:number)
    if FilterByte == 0 then -- None
        return Byte
    elseif FilterByte == 1 then -- Sub
        return Byte + ByteA
    elseif FilterByte == 2 then -- Up
        return Byte + ByteB
    elseif FilterByte == 3 then -- Average
        -- Average(x) + floor((ByteA + ByteB) / 2)
        return Byte + math.floor((ByteA + ByteB) / 2)
    elseif FilterByte == 4 then -- Paeth Predictor
        local P:number = ByteA + ByteB - ByteC
        local PA:number = math.abs(P - ByteA)
        local PB:number = math.abs(P - ByteB)
        local PC:number = math.abs(P - ByteC)
        local PR:number
        if (PA <= PB) and (PA <= PC) then 
            PR = ByteA
        elseif PB <= PC then 
            PR = ByteB
        else 
            PR = ByteC
        end
        return Byte + PR
    end
end
```

Comment: I have a working [Lua PNG decoder for Minetest](https://github.com/appgurueu/modlib/blob/master/minetest/png.lua) (tested against PNGSuite). It uses `minetest.decompress` for zlib decompression, but otherwise should be portable.